# Swap values in a tuple/list inside a list in python?

Tags: python, list, tuples, swap

I have a list of tuples like this:

```
[('foo','bar'),('foo1','bar1'),('foofoo','barbar')]
```

What is the fastest way in python (running on a very low cpu/ram machine) to swap values like this...

```
[('bar','foo'),('bar1','foo1'),('barbar','foofoo')]
```

I am currently using:

```
for x in mylist:
    self.my_new_list.append(((x[1]),(x[0])))
```

Is there a better or faster way???

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You could use map:

```
map (lambda t: (t[1], t[0]), mylist)
```

Or list comprehension:

```
[(t[1], t[0]) for t in mylist]
```

List comprehensions are preferred and supposedly much faster than map when lambda is needed, however note that list comprehension has a strict evaluation, that is it will be evaluated as soon as it gets bound to variable, if you're worried about memory consumption use a *generator* instead:

```
g = ((t[1], t[0]) for t in mylist)
#call when you need a value
g.next()
```

There are some more details here: [Python List Comprehension Vs. Map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247486/python-list-comprehension-vs-map)

Answer (score 14):

You can use `reversed` like this:

```
tuple(reversed((1, 2)) == (2, 1)
```

To apply it to a list, you can use `map` or a list/generator comprehension:

```
map(tuple, map(reversed, tuples))     # map
[tuple(reversed(x)) for x in tuples]  # list comprehension
(tuple(reversed(x)) for x in tuples)  # generator comprehension
```

If you're interested primarily in runtime speed, I can only recommend that you profile the various approaches and pick the fastest.

Answer (score 5):

A fancy way:

```
[t[::-1] for t in mylist]
```

Answer (score 3):

Using a **list comprehension** I find more elegant and understandable to use separate variables instead of indices for a single variable as in the solution provided by @iabdalkader:

```
[(b, a) for a, b in mylist]
```

Answer (score 0):

To modify the current list in-place, the most efficient way is:

```
my_list[:] = [(y, x)  for x, y in my_list]
```

It is assigning to the *list slice*, which covers the *entire list*, without creating an extra duplicate of the list in memory. See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1208792/967621).