# Change elements in a list from (x,y) to (y,x)?

Tags: python

I have the list `l`, with `(x,y)` pairs:

```
print(l)
[(4.476784, 50.820377), (4.466914, 50.83413), (4.466898, 50.843526), (4.461776, 50.84864), (4.460908, 50.850731), (4.461256, 50.851948)...]
```

I would like to switch the positions of the elements; that is, from `(x,y)` to `(y,x)`. How could I do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want it to modify the original list or create a new one? (In both cases, it's a `for`-loop, just slightly different)

Comment: What have you tried? Which part  is troubling you? Reading the existing values, swapping them, or writing them back?

Comment: The most efficient way is to modify the list in-place: `l[:] = [(y, x)  for x, y in l]`

Comment: The most efficient way would be to not change anything and simply read them backwards...

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the
[intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
"Write this code for me" is off-topic for Stack Overflow.
You have to make an honest attempt at the solution, and then ask a *specific* question about your implementation.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it using *list comprehension* as:

```
l = [(4.476784, 50.820377), (4.466914, 50.83413), (4.466898, 50.843526), (4.461776, 50.84864), (4.460908, 50.850731), (4.461256, 50.851948)]

new_list = [x[::-1]  for x in l]
```

OR,

```
new_list = [(y, x)  for x, y in l]
```

where `new_list` holds:

```
[(50.820377, 4.476784), (50.83413, 4.466914), (50.843526, 4.466898), (50.84864, 4.461776), (50.850731, 4.460908), (50.851948, 4.461256)]
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51755571/6045800

Comment: @Tomerikoo It would be better to flag the question as duplicate than to comment on an answer ;)

Comment: @zvone As you might notice the question is already closed as a duplicate of the question to which I linked an answer... Just trying to show that this answer exists already and there is no reason to repeat it...

Answer (score 1):

```
[(y, x) for x, y in l]
```

Tuples are immutable, so you can't literally reverse the tuples.

Comment: Can't modify the tuples, true, but might overwrite the same list, if there is need for that.

Comment: Agreed.  It was unclear what the poster wanted.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55062279/6045800