# How to reverse a list of latitude and longitude coordinate pairs?

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a list of tuples where each tuple contains a pair of coordinates. I would like to reverse the coordinates for each point.

I have a dataframe, and a specific column called "coord" contains a list of latitude and longitude coordinate pairs at each row, and I would like to reverse the pair of coordinates of each row.

As an example, the first row looks like this

```py
 [(52.34725, 4.91790),
 (52.34715, 4.91797),
 (52.34742, 4.91723),
 (52.34752, 4.91713)]
```

I tried this function, but it does not work.

```
result =  [[p[1], p[0]] for p in x]
```

The expected output is:

```py
[(4.91790, 52.34725),
 (4.91797, 52.34715),
 (4.91723, 52.34742),
 (4.91713, 52.34752)]
```

Comment: What does "*it does not work*" mean? Do you get errors or is it not what you expected? Your attempt should have worked in swapping the 2 items, but it creates a list of lists, instead of a list of tuples. You should have used `(p[1],p[0])`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Swap values in a tuple/list inside a list in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13384841/swap-values-in-a-tuple-list-inside-a-list-in-python)

Comment: i got the same input ,without reverse . i am no sure why but other method reversed down works fine for me .thanks for help

Comment: It may be because it's in a dataframe, which isn't shown here.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
reversed = [item[::-1] for item in x]
```

Comment: thanks , this works for me . i tried it for first row and it works  but how could i do it for each row in specific column ?

Comment: It is hard to understand what you want to achieve from this comment. Could you update your question, or post another question including the dataframe and a more clear desired output?

Comment: it is fine ,it worked great nw .tahnks for help

Answer (score 0):

```py
y = [(xx[1],xx[0]) for xx in x]
y  # [(4.9179, 52.34725), (4.91797, 52.34715), (4.91723, 52.34742), (4.91713, 52.34752)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution:

```
y = []
for i, j in x:
  y.append((j, i))
```

Output:

```
[(4.9179, 52.34725), (4.91797, 52.34715), (4.91723, 52.34742), (4.91713, 52.34752)]
```

Comment: , i have tried ur method but i got ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Comment: It works fine here, @Dragon!